# javascript manipulate a child window from his parent

Tags: javascript, parent, communication

I am currently trying to manipulate a child window with javascript written in its parent. So far I have this:

```
    <!doctype html />

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var otherW;

            function open_win() {
                otherW = window.open("https://www.youtube.com/", "otherW", "width=500, height=500, resizable");
                setTimeout("delay()", 5000);
            }

            function delay() {
                otherW.moveTo(20, 50);
            }
        </script>
        <title>Parent</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="open_win()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason it doesn't work. Is it possible at all to manipulate a child window when another website is loaded in it. The code above works fine when I pass an empty string instead of the youtube url.

What I was trying to do at the very beginning was to create a script in the parent window, the script was supposed to open a specific site in a new child window when a button was clicked. Then using a reference to the new window, I was supposed to set values to some input type="text" fields. Unfortunately it didn't work so I tried with much easier and easier test and finally realized that even something simple as the code above doesn't work. Please note that if I replace moveTo method with close(), it works fine - the child window closes after 5secs. I tried it with Firefox. With Opera it only opens the child window.

Any help/suggestions/ideas will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like `moveTo()` is a property of a `window` object (inside the opened window). You can't access `window` in a third party page.

Comment: Then I guess otherW.document.getElementsByTagName("name")[o].value="somevalue"  won't work ask well?

Comment: Yep, you're right with this. This is called [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Even if you'd open a page from your own domain to a pop-up, some browsers have an option, which can block `moveTo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, why don't you simply try:

```
window.open("https://www.youtube.com/", "otherW", "width=500, height=500, top=50, left=20, resizable");
```

this should not interfere with the same-origin policy.